# Why can't I see flames through the camera?

Tags: smoke-simulation

While making a cheesy rocket, I noticed I cannot see the flames through the camera.  I can see them in ortho and perspective view when set to render view mode, so I don't believe it is a material issue.

Here is a screen shot showing the issue:
[image: I believe the materials are correct and nothing is hidden.]

Here is a second screen shot, in which I change the domain's material to simply an emission so it is not weighted by smoke density. 
[image: Image showing issue in greater detail]

It almost looks like the active smoke domain is cutting out the flame, but why this would happen, let alone only happen in camera mode, is perplexing to me.  Also, the below does not reflect adaptive smoke domain (unselected).

Comment: Try to untick "Clamp" in your multiply node, it limits the output to 1

Comment: Something appears to be masking that area, like when you have a hole in the domain.

Comment: Removing the clamp did not do it.

Comment: Matt, it does look like there is something masking the flame, but why would it only mask when looking through the camera? Also, there are no other items in the scene that could mask.